# Sending data using system calls in Java (Flex project)

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml, system-calls

I am constructing an application using flex. I want to be able to send data from one device (a tablet) to another (mobile phone) and vice-versa.I haven't found a way to do this using flex and heard that maybe using system calls might allow me to do this. I don't think there is a way to make system calls in flex, but I know that I can in Java.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Sending the data? Using system calls or any other method?

And will I be able to combine the Java code into my flex project?

Comment: By sharing data, I mean: If I create a list on a tablet, I want to be able to view the list on the mobile phone and then be able to add to the list on the mobile phone which will then inevitably change the list on the tablet. I would like to implement this functionality in my application.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke Java from Flex, you will have to create an Adobe Native Extension.
A nice tuto is available [here](http://blog.teamthinklabs.com/index.php/2013/07/31/adobe-native-extensions-the-untold-story/)

Could you provide more details about what you want to achieve? Sharing data between devices is really vague and could be achieved with very different solutions depending on the context.